# Python gdal undefined symbol GDALRasterBandGetVirtualMem

Tags: python, gdal

I'm trying to use [Python GDAL bindings](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL).  When naively installing bindings through pip, installation fails with [error: 'VSIFTruncateL' was not declared in this scope](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/21269/4904), probably due to a mismatch of the installed headers and the python bindings version.  The [proposed solution elsewhere](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/23407/4904) is to install the exact same version through pip.  However, my system has `gdal-1.7.3`, and there are no 1.7.3 bindings.  Installing [1.7.1 bindings](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/1.7.1) leads to successful compilation, but attempting to run leads to `undefined symbol: GDALRasterBandGetVirtualMem`.  Therefore, [I installed 1.11.1 from source](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2012-April/032598.html) and compiled the latest bindings against it.  Compilation and installation appears to work, but importing does not:

```
In [2]: import osgeo
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-26b16a6d02ad> in <module>()
----> 1 import osgeo

/export/data/home/gholl/venv/gerrit/lib/python3.4/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py in <module>()
     19                 fp.close()
     20             return _mod
---> 21     _gdal = swig_import_helper()
     22     del swig_import_helper
     23 else:

/export/data/home/gholl/venv/gerrit/lib/python3.4/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py in swig_import_helper()
     15         if fp is not None:
     16             try:
---> 17                 _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
     18             finally:
     19                 fp.close()

/export/data/home/gholl/venv/gerrit/lib64/python3.4/imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, details)
    241                 return load_dynamic(name, filename, opened_file)
    242         else:
--> 243             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
    244     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:
    245         return load_package(name, filename)

ImportError: /export/data/home/gholl/venv/gerrit/lib/python3.4/site-packages/osgeo/_gdal.cpython-34m.so: undefined symbol: GDALRasterBandGetVirtualMem
```

I'm at a loss now.  What else can I try to use `gdal` and its Python bindings?

(The system is `Scientific Linux release 6.6 (Carbon)` on which I do not have system administrator access.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If a gdal version is already installed, this problem will occur even if you have linked against the version installed in `~/.local`.

A solution is given at [a Planet MYSQL post here](http://fr.planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=683010):

> In this case, we can tell the linker to preload our newer 1.11.0 library in our shell this way:
>
> ```
> export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libgdal.so.1
> ```

Or, in my case,

> ```
> export LD_PRELOAD="$HOME/.local/lib/libgdal.so.1"
> ```

Indeed, this solves the problem.

Comment: This saved my life. Couldn't get rid of all leftovers of a GDAL source installation and almost got crazy. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I run:
   export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libgdal.so.1
before pythod command, it's fixed