# Permanently define environment variable (for Python gdal undefined symbol)

Tags: python, linux

I have installed gdal version 1.11.2, however I have problems with undefined symbols. A proposed solution for this is given by [gerrit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27134273/5316326):

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libgdal.so.1
```

However, this only works if I call the python script from the command line. If I call the script from a `subprocess.Popen`, this will obviously not work.

Is there a way to define the `LD_PRELOAD` permanently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can save the export in your /etc/environment if you want to have it globally for every user

or you can use the env argument like so:

```
subprocess.Popen(command, env={'LD_PRELOAD': '/usr/local/lib/libgdal.so.1'})
```

see also here:
[Python subprocess/Popen with a modified environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231227/python-subprocess-popen-with-a-modified-environment)

Comment: thanks, should this work when the script runs under sudo or root?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution IMHO is to fix the problem at OS level. If you want `gdal`to be accessible to only some users of your platform, each user should add the line

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libgdal.so.1
```

in his own `.profile` file (assuming they all use bash or a compatible shell)

Alternatively, if all users should be able to use `gdal`, that line should be added to the system `/etc/profile` file.